# How to update Target Position in DOMoveY if during moving target position changed

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

How to update Target Position in DOMoveY if during moving target position changed, Like I'm running that function with duration of 1f and if within that 1f target position changed how can I update in DOMoveY?
Here is code

```
for (int col = 0; col < gridColumns; col++)
{

    for (int row = 0; row < gridRows; row++)
    {
        if (gridPositions[row, col].tag == "empty")
        {
            int c_row = (row + 1) > 6 ? 6 : (row + 1);
            if (gridPositions[c_row, col].tag != "empty")
            {
                if (c_row < 6)
                {

                    gridPositions[row + 1, col].transform.DOMoveY(EmptyBlocks[row, col].transform.position.y, 1f, false);
                    gridPositions[row, col] = gridPositions[row + 1, col];

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by combining `OnUpdate` and `ChangeEndValue` functions. Inside ChangeEndValue function, you need to pass the required Vector3 that can change/update.

```
for (int col = 0; col < gridColumns; col++)
{      
    for (int row = 0; row < gridRows; row++)
    {
        if (gridPositions[row, col].tag == "empty")
        {
            int c_row = (row + 1) > 6 ? 6 : (row + 1);
            if (gridPositions[c_row, col].tag != "empty")
            {
                if (c_row < 6)
                {
                                
                    var moveTween = gridPositions[row + 1, col].transform.DOMoveY(EmptyBlocks[row, col].transform.position.y, 1f, false);
                    var updatedVector3 = new Vector3(gridPositions[row + 1, col].transform.position.x, EmptyBlocks[row, col].transform.position.y, gridPositions[row + 1, col].transform.position.z);
                    moveTween.OnUpdate(()=>moveTween.ChangeEndValue(updatedVector3, true));
                    gridPositions[row, col] = gridPositions[row + 1, col];
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still have same issue, actually target is changing it's position constantly  but the object is reaching to old position instead of new  updated Y position.

Comment: Like i have stated in my answer, you need to pass the changing position to `ChangeEndValue` function.